# Can't use removeChild() to delete the element just appended to list. Can only delete the ones at the beginning

Tags: javascript, appendchild, removechild

This is two button. One is "**appendChild**" ,One is "**Remove Child".**

**List** ----Before------------

1. one
2. two
3. three
4. appended
5. appended

-------------------------

After appended two new elements, I want to remove the last one. But when I press the remove button.

**List** ---After-------------

1. one
2. two
3. (?????????? be deleted)
4. appended
5. appended

-------------------------

The appended elements are still there. I see many solve this problem with jQuery, but I am totally new. I am wondering if JavaScript has the solution.

```js
apd.onclick = function() {
    let apd = document.getElementById('apd')
    let node = document.createElement('li')
    node.className = 'added'
    let textnode = document.createTextNode('this is node content')
    node.appendChild(textnode)
  
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(node)
}

let list = document.getElementById('list')
let rem = document.getElementById('rem')
rem.onclick = function() {
    let node = document.createElement('li')
  
    document.getElementById('list').removeChild(list.children[0])
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<button id="apd">click me to append child!</button>
<button id="rem">click me to remove child!</button>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.getElementById('list')` inside the click functions if you've already saved it in the variable `list`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's exactly what he wrote.

Comment: Two issues with the code that jump out: 1. You're relying on automatic DOM globals for `apd` in the initial `apd.onclick = /*...*/;`, but then using `getElementById` to look it up later. It's best not to rely on automatic DOM globals at all because of potential conflicts, etc.; use `getElementById` to get the element (just once is fine). 2. You're assigning functions to `onclick`. While that works, in general its best to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: By `list.children[0]` you are explicitly asking for the first child element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.lastElementChild.remove();` for delete problem and instead of onclick event use `addEventListener` as suggest by @T.J- Crowder into comment like:

```js
let list = document.getElementById('list')
let rem = document.getElementById('rem')
let apd = document.getElementById('apd')
apd.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let node = document.createElement('li')
  let textnode = document.createTextNode('this is node content')
  node.className = 'added'  
  node.appendChild(textnode)
  list.appendChild(node)
});
rem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  list.lastElementChild.remove();
  //or if you need application for IE use list.removeChild(list.lastElementChild);
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>123125151</li>
  <li>123125151</li>
  <li>123125151</li>
  <li>123125151</li>
  <li>123125151</li>
</ul>
<button id="apd">click me to append child!</button>
<button id="rem">click me to remove child!</button>
```

Reference:

- [Element.lastElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild)
- [Element.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) - note: not on Internet Explorer, you'd need `removeChild` on the parent instead
- [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the first one and not the last one.

Instead of list.children[0], you can use list.children[list.children.length - 1] which will be the last one.

```js
apd.onclick = function() {
    let apd = document.getElementById('apd')
    let node = document.createElement('li')
    node.className = 'added'
    let textnode = document.createTextNode('this is node content')
    node.appendChild(textnode)
  
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(node)
}

let list = document.getElementById('list')
let rem = document.getElementById('rem')
rem.onclick = function() {
    let node = document.createElement('li')
  
    document.getElementById('list').removeChild(list.children[list.children.length - 1])
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<button id="apd">click me to append child!</button>
<button id="rem">click me to remove child!</button>
```